# Android issue with change fragment into onPostExecute

Tags: java, android

I simply trying to change my fragment on post execute. 
There are case :

```
            case 4:

                try {
                    String code = this.result.getString("code");
                    if (code.equals("200"))
                    {
                        final String stepString = "step";
                        setValue(stepString, "3");
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                    }
                    else if (code.equals("400"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), this.result.getString("text"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            break;
        }
```

And also i have class that named `HomeFragment`

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        myImage = (ImageView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.home_logo);
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        String wifiName = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ().getSSID ();
        wifiName = wifiName.replace("\"" ,"");



        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And i have NUll Pointer error. But why? I have class HomeFragment..

There are Log.cat

```
10-16 12:09:10.744    4700-4700/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity$PlanetFragment$JSONAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:545)
            at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity$PlanetFragment$JSONAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:404)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: At which line you are getting exception? Show your 404 line number.

Comment: here `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment()).commit();`

Comment: `RootView` should be `rootView` whit the lower case `r`

Comment: but where i need to do changes?

Comment: Check this id content_frame is correct?

Comment: How i can to check it?

Comment: In your xml layout file

Comment: yes because before i has done some fragment change with this code